# Tilemill (Carto) code for styling multiple features from a single layer

Tags: web-mapping, mapnik, tilemill

How can I more efficiently write this piece of code which aims to style two features in my streets layer (major roads and major road ramps) the exact same way.

```
#tor_centreline [FCODE=201200] {
      line-width: 0.5;
      line-color: lightgray;
   }

#tor_centreline [FCODE=201201] {
      line-width: 0.5;
      line-color: lightgray;
   }
```

When I input the code as...

```
#tor_centreline [FCODE=201200],[FCODE=201201] {
```

... I break my map because I believe the second [FCODE=""] is not linked to the #tor_centreline... such that it searches all of my layers for [FCODE=""] and when it finds a layer with no "FCODE" attribute field I receive an error.

Answer (score 6):

([Cross-posting from GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/456#issuecomment-1550546) for the benefit of StackExchangers..)

Both filters must be connected to a layer selector. There are two options that require only specifying the style once:

```
#tor_centreline [FCODE=201200],
#tor_centreline [FCODE=201201] {
  line-width: 0.5;
  line-color: lightgray;
}
```

or

```
#tor_centreline {
  [FCODE=201200],
  [FCODE=201201] {
    line-width: 0.5;
    line-color: lightgray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#tor_centreline {
    [FCODE=201200] {line-width: 0.5; line-color: lightgray;}
    [FCODE=201201] {line-width: 0.5; line-color: lightgray;}
}
```

see: http://support.mapbox.com/kb/tilemill/styling-point-data-using-tilemill